# Slower if temp variable is used for indexing?

Tags: c++, loops

I am reading a math-related source code in C++. There are lots of loops **resembling** the first loop in my example below. I thought they could be more efficient if I store some temp variables for indexing. However, I was wrong.

**I intended to store the result of `i * 8` in order to reduce to number of multiplication.** The following example is simplified. The original case could be more complicated. **Is my effort to reduce the number of multiplication useless in cases similar to this one?**

```
// Without register
Old
Time: 8.8
New
Time: 9.0
```

Contrary to my intuition, it's slower if I use temp variable!

---

Then I used `register` to store the temp variable and it turned out to be faster if I use temp variable.

```
// With register
Old
Time: 8.9
New
Time: 7.8
```

If writing a speed-intensive app that involves lots of calculations as such, should I rely on the optimization by compiler or on `register`? If multi-thread, will `register` cause any problem?

---

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

#define DIM 10000
#define COUNT 100000
int main() {
  clock_t start, end;
  double mtx[8 * DIM] = {0};
  printf("Old\n");
  start = clock();
  for (int count = 0; count < COUNT; ++count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; ++i) {
      mtx[i * 8 + 0] += 1;
      mtx[i * 8 + 1] += 1;
      mtx[i * 8 + 2] += 1;
      mtx[i * 8 + 3] += 1;
      mtx[i * 8 + 4] += 1;
      mtx[i * 8 + 5] += 1;
      mtx[i * 8 + 6] += 1;
      mtx[i * 8 + 7] += 1;
    }
  }
  end = clock();
  printf("Time: %2.1lf\n", (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  printf("New\n");
  start = clock();
  /* register */ int j;
  for (int count = 0; count < COUNT; ++count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; ++i) {
      j = i * 8;
      mtx[j + 0] += 1;
      mtx[j + 1] += 1;
      mtx[j + 2] += 1;
      mtx[j + 3] += 1;
      mtx[j + 4] += 1;
      mtx[j + 5] += 1;
      mtx[j + 6] += 1;
      mtx[j + 7] += 1;
    }
  }
  end = clock();
  printf("Time: %2.1lf\n", (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  return 0;
}
```

---

I'm not very familiar with the command line options of `g++`. I just used `g++ efficiency.cpp` in the above example. Then, I tried `-O2` option, and the time consumed is reduced to `0.0` in both cases.

Comment: `-S` ftw. Its what's for dinner. You never mentioned if *all* of the aforementioned sample runs were compiled in release-mode with identical optimization ferocity.

Comment: This is not compiled with optimization, because in that case, the compiler should eliminate the loops because no result is expected from the loops.  But that also means that timing micro-optimizations is meaningless.

Comment: No compiler command line -> unanswerable question.

Comment: My test with your code: `Old: 20.4 New: 9.9`. Compiling with `-O3` and using the result leads to `Old: 6.1 New: 6.1`

Comment: `-O2` detects that you do not use the array and deletes the loops entirely.

Comment: maybe you can eliminate a for loop if you use `+= COUNT;` instead of `+= 1;`

Comment: I would be very surprised when the `register` keyword made any difference as most compilers simply completely ignore it.

Comment: `j = i * 8;` --> shouldn't that be `j += 8;` (with proper initialization)? I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler figured that out automatically though.

Comment: @Csq I could use `j++` (`j` is 0 initially) directly for indexing, but I use `i * 8` to clarify my intention to reduce multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am interpreting the following to constitute your question.

> If writing a speed-intensive app that involves lots of calculations as
>   such, should I rely on the optimization by compiler or on register? If
>   multi-thread, will register cause any problem?

First of all, if you are aiming for (and trying to measure) efficiency of a program, you should always be running with at least `-O2` if not `-O3`, depending on what is used in production.

After the compiler has done everything it can for you, you can *then* consider hand-optimizations such as using `register` variables. Most of the time, you will find that the `register` keyword is either ignored by the compiler, or does not help your performance significantly.

The short answer to the question of whether multithreading will cause any problems with the use of `register` is **no**. Having said that, there are many ways to write incorrect multithreaded programs even without `register`.

---

Related issue mentioned in the question: Why are your timings all close to zero when you run with optimizations on?

If the compiler can determine through static analysis that either the result of the loops is never used, or the loops themselves can be replaced by a simpler computation (perhaps adding `COUNT` directly), then it will go ahead and do that, which will tend to cut down the time substantially.

The only way to know for sure is to use `gcc -S -O2` to show the assembly after a particular optimization, and determine from the assembly whether the loops are still there.